# Why am I getting vector subscript out of range?

Tags: c++, vector, stack

This is a segment of my code and the only active part of it right now as the rest is commented out, and I'm trying to create a vector of stacks which stacks plates 10 high and then creates a new stack. It's my first time working with stacks really so i dont know if i declared the vector correctly or whatever..

But more importantly whenever i try to push an item onto the stack via the for loop, i get an error: vector subscript out of range line: 1234 and I'm not sure how i should be pushing onto the stack or if there is a way to use trains.push_back(). (Everytime i try push_back, i get an error).

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
vector<stack<int>> plates;
int numPlates,plateColor;
int x = 0;

cout << "Enter number of Plates" << endl;
cin >> numPlates;

for (int i = 0; i < numPlates; i++) {
    if ((x + 1) % 10 == 0) // once plates are stacked ten high, start new stack
        x++;
    cin >> plateColor;
    plates[x].push(plateColor);
}
```

Comment: You don't show where "trains" is defined.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: its supposed to be plates.. I fixed it

Comment: Your vector is empty. You have to put some elements in there before you can use `plates[x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the stack, fill it, then use emplace_back to add it to the vector.  Something like this should work:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < numPlates; i += 10 ) 
{
    stack<int> temp = stack<int>();
    for ( int j = 0; j < 10 && j + i < numPlates; j++ );
    {
        int plateColor = 0;
        cin >> plateColor;
        temp.push( plateColor );
    }
    plates.emplace_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. Sorry if my question was too vague, but this is exactly what i needed to know. Now on to figure out how to print out stack contents within the vector... Thanks again

Comment: @alwaysLearning - You will need 2 nested loops.  1 to iterate through the vector and another to get the individual values from each stack.  You can use the stack::empty() function as the limit.  Remember that getting the top value only reads it.  You still need to pop the value off to be able to read the next one.

Answer (score 0):

When X is 0, or whenever X in incremented, you need to push a new Stack into plates[x]